# Range tripped circuit now will not work

Tags: electrical, range

Whilrpool electric Range, 6 years old.  While boiling pasta sauce and water on top of stove and heating oven, heard a pop and all power went dead.  Reset circuit but range will not power back up.  House is built in 1998.  Reset circuit several times, check all GFCI which are working properly.

Family of 6, range is used daily, this was very typical use.

Suggestions what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Turn the breaker off, pull the range out, and unplug it.  Remove the access panel on the back (if there is one), and inspect the wiring where the cord attaches to the range. My guess is that you'll see one of the wires is disconnected, and/or one or more wires are charred/melted.

This is a fairly common problem, as I described in [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/70105/33). Depending on the amount of damage, the repair could range anywhere from simply replacing the cord, to replacing/rewiring the range.

Answer (score 0):

If the circuit breaker tripped and won't reset, there's usually a good reason for it. Either a short within the appliance or along the wiring, or an overload condition.

On the other hand, the breaker itself could be old and worn out. (It happens.) The first thing to try is to replace the breaker in the panel and see if the problem persists. (If you're not comfortable doing this, call an electrician or knowledgeable acquaintance.) The breaker **must** be replaced by a breaker of identical amperage and make/model of your panel.

If the new breaker also trips, then there is a problem with the appliance or the circuit itself. That will probably require some outside expertise to diagnose and repair.

Comment: Replacing the breaker is **not** the first step in this case. Inspecting the range, and trying to determine what caused the breaker to trip is.

Comment: If you pull out the stove and unplug it, try to turn the breaker back on. If the breaker trips out immediately without the stove being turned on, then you have a fault somewhere in your circuit. If the circuit stays on, then there is a problem with your stove.